# Open a file program w/ while loop C++

Tags: c++, file, loops, while-loop, fltk

so here are my instructions to create a while loop to open a file called ‘G:/points.dat’

This is my code so far. I'm struggling to create the for loop that reads through the file, prints them to the monitor and then using those integers as x, y points. I can understand naming the x and y parameters, but im struggling with the loop itself

```
#include "Window.h"
#include "Colours.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
// create a new window of size 500 x 500 pixels
// the top left corner of the window is (0,0)
    SPA::Window window(500,500,"My Test");
    ifstream myInputFile;
    string inputFileName = "G:/points,dat";

    myInputFile.open(inputFileName);

    int i = 0;
    myInputFile >> i;

    myInputFile.close();

    window.show(argc,argv);

    return Fl::run();
}
```

- Open file ‘G:/points.dat’
- Read in multiple pairs of numbers – ie two numbers per line until the
  end of the file
- You should use a while loop and appropriate tests of the file state to detect the end of file
- the eof flag only gets set to true after you have tried to read at least one value beyond the end of the file.
- Each pair of numbers represents the x and y coordinates (x,y) of a point on a line to be drawn.

  - Inside your loop add a point to the current line for each (x,y) value you read in

Comment: You need a type that represents points and a collection of such points.

Comment: After following molbdnilo's recommendation, [give Option 2 of this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301) a read for ideas on how to load the point-containing type. Also worth [looking into creating a `>>` overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) for this type because it can turn the main program logic into a dead-stupid `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The loop is easy enough

```
while (myInputFile >> x >> y)
{
    // do something with x and y
    ...
}
```

That loop doesn't strictly read two values per line, it just reads the next two values whether they are on the next line or not.

BTW you have a typo in your code

```
string inputFileName = "G:/points,dat";
```

should be

```
string inputFileName = "G:/points.dat";
```

When you open a file you should **always** check to see if it opened successfully.